# From List<string[]> to String[,]

Tags: c#, .net, list, multidimensional-array

I have a problem here and it seems that my brain has just left the building so I need you guys to help me out. I have an API - method which requires a multidimensional string array. It looks like this:

```
string[,] specialMacroArray = new string[,] { { "#macro#", "text1" }, {"#secondmacro#", "text2"} }
```

The contents of the array are calculated throughout my method and therefor I cannot write it like above. So I put the values in a List throughout my code like this:

```
List<string[]> specialMacros = new List<string[]>();
specialMacros.Add(new string[] { "#macro#", text1 });
specialMacros.Add(new string[] { "#secondmacro#", "text2" });
```

So far so good... but now I want to convert the list to the multidimensional array. But I can't figure out how.

```
specialMacroArray = specialMacros.ToArray()
```

I am using the .NET 3.5 Framework in C#

Thanx in advance

Comment: I think you'll have to just declare a new `string[,]` variable and use nested foreach loops to populate it.

Comment: Have you considered using loops?

Comment: +1 for not asking "how can I do this in one line with LINQ?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this case you could just do this:

```
specialMacroArray = new string[specialMacros.Count, 2];
for (int i = 0; i < specialMacros.Count; i++)
{
    specialMacroArray[i, 0] = specialMacros[i][0];
    specialMacroArray[i, 1] = specialMacros[i][1];
}
```

Comment: I've got spoiled rotten by those Linq methods I have never even thought about creating the array myself. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably have to do it manually. Something like this:

```
string[,] array = new string[specialMacroArray.Count, 2]

for (int i=0; i<specialMacroArray.Count; ++i)
{
    array[i, 0] = specialMacroArray[i][0];
    array[i, 1] = specialMacroArray[i][1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help you

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace sandbox
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string[]> specialMacros = new List<string[]>();
            specialMacros.Add(new string[] { "#macro#", "text1" }); 
            specialMacros.Add(new string[] { "#secondmacro#", "text2" });
            var op = specialMacros.ToMultiDimensionalArray();
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
    public static class ArrayHelper
    {
        public static string[,] ToMultiDimensionalArray(this List<string[]> dt)
        {
            int col = dt.FirstOrDefault().ToList().Count();

            string[,] arr = new string[dt.Count, col];
            int r = 0;
            foreach (string[] dr  in dt)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < col; c++)
                {
                    arr[r, c] = dr[c];
                }
                r++;
            }
            return arr;
        }
    }


}
```

Based on the some of comments I have edited the function but I believe this user can make his own judgement and improve the code if they need to.

```
 public static string[,] ToMultiDimensionalArray(this List<string[]> dt)
        {
           if (dt.Count == 0 )
               throw new ArgumentException("Input arg has no elemets");
           int col = dt[0].Count();
            string[,] arr = new string[dt.Count, col];
            int r = 0;
            foreach (string[] dr in dt)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < col; c++)
                {
                    arr[r, c] = dr[c];
                }
                r++;
            }
            return arr;
        }
```

Comment: While there are many things wrong with this solution, perhaps the biggest is that it returns `object[,]` instead of `string[,]`.

Comment: well that is fixed and i am sure anyone could have fixed that... what are the other things wrong with code ..

Comment: Changing to public static T[,] ToMultiDimensionalArray<T>(this List<T[]> dt) would be a start.  Bounds checking is also needed.  Also, dt[0].Length will give you the number of items in the first array rather than using that Linq.

Comment: @david_001 - Why I want to return T[,] when user wants a string[,] and second I have some faith in person asking the question. I am sure in my 2 mins I took to write this the other person can check for out of bound exception... dt[0].Length is fine but I dont have a problem with that LINQ there.. I am sure there are more than 1 way to check the length of frist item here.

Comment: Think about what `dt.FirstOrDefault().ToList().Count()` does and see if you can simplify it. What happens if you pass in an empty list?

Comment: @gabe . well it is not hardcoded to 2 as you did I didnt intend toto check for null , empty string and completely bake the solution . I am use @turBas could have done it..  fine I will edit it ...

Comment: @gabe done. I dont wish to build an extension method which complements ToArray(). This was just to give an solution ... Remove Static class and this and it can be made a normal method or I can add more constraints check the type of the input and the list can go on for ever..

Answer (score 0):

```
string[][] specialMacroArray = new string[][] { new string[] { "#macro#", "text1" }, new string[] { "#secondmacro#", "text2" } };
        List<string[]> specialMacros = new List<string[]>();
        specialMacros.Add(new string[] { "#macro1#", "text1" });
        specialMacros.Add(new string[] { "#secondmacro#", "text2" });
        specialMacroArray = specialMacros.ToArray();
```

works fine, no loop is needed... all u have to do is change `string[,]` to `string[][]` (that's array of array, initializes in a bit diff way)

updated code:

```
List<string[,]> specialMacros = new List<string[,]>();
specialMacros.Add(new string[,] { { "#secondmacro#", "text2" }, { "#secondmacro#", "text2" } });
specialMacroArray =specialMacros[0];
```

Comment: I think you've missed the point that it's an external API call - he can't change the API method to accept string[][] instead of string[,]

Comment: Sorry, can't do. Perhaps I didn't state it clearly but I use an external API and I can't change the signature of the methods of the API

Comment: my bad, I really missed the point. Anyways... have changed code, maybe this will fit: 

`List<string[,]> specialMacros = new List<string[,]>();`


`specialMacros.Add(new string[,] { { "#secondmacro#", "text2" }, { "#secondmacro#", "text2" } });`

`specialMacroArray =specialMacros[0];`